# jquery .css a:link of a jquery object

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to use the jQuery.css() property to color property of a link. The straightforward way would be to use

```
var $el = $("#test a:link"); //don't want to use this
$el.css({"color"  : "red"});
```

but I already have $el defined and used in multiple other places as

```
var $el = $("#test");
```

Can I still access the a:link a:visited a:hover a:active properties by reusing $el combined with some other code?

```
($el/*other code to access a:link of #test*/)
.css({"color"  : "red"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RUYfZ/1/ Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery takes an [optional 'context' parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) allowing you to search inside an existing result:

```
var $el = $("#test"); 
$('a:link', $el).css({"color"  : "red"});
```

The context can be a DOM element, document, or jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$el.find('a:link').css('color', 'red');
```

---

edit: applied this solution to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RUYfZ/3/

Also, not sure what you mean by using the :visited, :hover, :active pseudo-selectors.  jQuery selectors are used for querying the DOM, not for state-dependent styling.  Even in CSS, those pseudo-selectors all select the same DOM nodes, they just apply different styles depending on the state.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing to `$el` is assigning css properties, you don't even need to use the variable. Try the following

```
$('#test a:link').css('color', 'red')
```

Or, if $el is currently defined as `#test` (it points to the element with the id test), you can do

```
$('a:link', $el).css('color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$el` is in scope in the location you wish to use it, it can be reused. If `$el` is out of scope, you will need to assign it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's .children() selector method, where you give jQuery a selector to operate on the children of the given parent element, as such:
`$el.children('a:link')`

Comment: His original selector, "#test a:link", allows the anchor to be n-levels deep below #test. This example requires it to be an immediate child.  Using .find() will allow a deeper hierarchy.